# Distributed Multithreaded Checkpointing (DMTCP) between two hosts

Tags: multithreading

I am able to use DMTCP to checkpoint and restart a process in a single machine. But, I am not able to checkpoint a process in one system, moved the checkpoint file (.dmtcp) to another machine and restart the same.

According to the documentation of DMTCP, this should be possible.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you write the question to the dmtcp-forum mailing list on sourceforge? For more details here: http://dmtcp.sourceforge.net/contactUs.html